# Gnome Tweaks not showing Applications dropdown in the Appearance section

Tags: arch-linux, gnome

In the Gnome tweak tool, there is a Appearance section. In there, there SHOULD be a Applications dropdown menu. However, (and IDK whether this a Gnome 42 thing) there is no Applications menu. Please help, and I am willing to try different alternatives to GNOME Tweak Tool.

Oh and I use Arch. (seriously, no joke)

Here is a screenshot:
[image: GNOME Tweaks with a missing dropdown...]

Comment: That's of odd. Could you post a screenshot of GNOME Tweaks? Also what version is it?

Comment: Ok, I am using GNOME Tweaks 42.beta (hmm, Arch Linux DOES have a habit of getting beta stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions management has been moved to a out of `gnome-tweaks` and into its own application: `gnome-extensions-app` (at least that's what it's called in Fedora). if you install `gnome-extensions-app`, you can find 'Applications Menu' there, as you can see from the screenshot below.
[image: GNOME Extensions application]

If you can't find 'Applications Menu' there, you'll have to manually install it. I do not know if Arch Linux ships it in their repos - if not - you can install it from [the official GNOME Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't clear. But in the Appearance section like you see in my screenshot was supposed to have a Applications dropdown for theming, not for getting the MATE-like menu up top.

Comment: Hold on. I'll check on my PC.

Comment: @AaravGupta Mine looks the same as yours. They've [removed the old one](https://eu-browse.startpage.com/av/anon-image?piurl=https%3A%2F%2Fnews-cdn.softpedia.com%2Fimages%2Fnews2%2Fgnome-tweak-tool-renamed-to-gnome-tweaks-will-learn-new-tweaks-for-gnome-3-26-517086-2.jpg&sp=1660581224T906ac80b98eaa22e7ba2084cb1b448e08129e6e257bc6710d1c06820dbcf066d) and replaced it with what we're both using now ('Legacy Applications' ). Are you experiencing trouble with your themes or something?

Comment: Yup Some apps are just using the normal theme, instead of the theme I would prefer, which I was assuming was a result of not having a Applications dropdown... in the Appearance section.

Comment: That may be an issue with the theme itself... have you checked that the theme supports GTK4? AFAIK, some themes need to be split up into different folders: `~/.config/gtk-3.0`, `~/.config/gtk-4.0`, and `~/.themes`. Also, as an addendum, Flatpaks *do not* like custom themes.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will go to Ubuntu now... (not that there isn't a problem with it).

Comment: I noticed that you use Graphite theme: is it the same as [this one](https://github.com/vinceliuice/Graphite-gtk-theme)? If so, did you follow the instructions on the creator's GitHub repo?

Comment: No, there is this guy named LinuxScoop, and he made a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igFkb18G4Zw

Comment: Yes, that's the same theme :) If you follow the instructions on the GH repo (unless you already did), the themes might work properly.

Comment: @AaravGupta If you use Flatpaks, you can use [Stylepak](https://github.com/refi64/stylepak) to get the same theme inside Flatpaks.

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-tweaks/blob/master/NEWS

and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71819004/gnome-tweaks-42-removes-duplicate-settings

Just downloaded **Orchis** gtk theme from gnome-look.org. Applied using Tweaks --> Appearance --> Legacy Applications.
Edit:
In the second link is mention of GTK_THEME. As an example, try

```
GTK_THEME=Sweet-Dark gnome-calculator &
```

or any other preferred theme. It will only apply to gnome-calculator.